# Validating Field - Default Value

Tags: list

SP 2013

I have a field in list called Status

This has a default value of 'Open'

I need to validate it so no other value except Open is in there

I have tried ="Open", =Status="Open"

This is probably simple - but not getting the correct syntax

Comment: Apologies if I'm not understanding correctly, but if there is only one valid value, it might be easier to just make a Read Only text field that you set with calculations or workflows than it would be to validate a value that shouldn't be changed. Let me know if there is something I'm not understanding correctly, and I'll do my best to help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying using this variation of an IF formula:

=IF([Status]="Open", 1, 0)

Cheers,

-Drew